# How to split/Copy/Move the text values according to the labelname to particular individual textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a main text box that inputs text file from my computer. The text file content is **N14G73X315.2Y83.7I40.0J6.4A0.0H3K75T11F5M0C0.0**.

[image]

So i want to pass the corresponding values to textboxes shown in the link below.

[image]

Right now i am able to upload the text file from computer to the textbox. Please help me how can i transfer the text from textbox to particular
textboxes with labels. Infornt of each number there is a Aplhabet. So i want to move/copy the particular number to the corresponding textboxes
with correspoding labels.
  Code i am trying..

```
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        textBox11.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way, this is really two questions not one. Splitting a string into multiple (sub) strings is the first.  And the second is populating a textbox (which is really fundamental).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
class Program
{
    static char[] alphabetArray1 = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
    static char[] alphabetArray2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    static List<char> characterSet = new List<char>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        characterSet = alphabetArray1.ToList<char>();
        characterSet.AddRange(alphabetArray2.ToList<char>());

        YourMethod(@"N14G73X315.2Y83.7I40.0J6.4A0.0H3K75T11F5M0C0.0");

    }

    static void YourMethod(string input)
    {
        Dictionary<char, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<char, string>();
        StringBuilder tempStr = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        int currIndex = 0;
        int prevCharIndex = 0;
        while (currIndex < input.Length)
        {

            if (characterSet.Contains(input[currIndex]))
            {
                //charIndex = currIndex;
                if (tempStr.Length > 0)
                {
                    dictionary[input[prevCharIndex]] = tempStr.ToString();
                    tempStr.Length = 0;
                }
                dictionary.Add(input[currIndex], string.Empty);
                prevCharIndex = currIndex;
            }
            else
            { 
                tempStr.Append(input[currIndex]); 
            }
            currIndex++;
        }
        if (tempStr.Length > 0)
        {
            dictionary[input[prevCharIndex]] = tempStr.ToString();
            tempStr.Length = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

After this you will have a dictionary of Alphabets and their corresponding values. AFter this, its all simple.

You will get values something like this:

Just map your values to corresponding text boxes. :)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Where i should give all the corresponding values

Comment: @ its giving an error called Error `has more than one entry point defined: 'creater.Form1.Program.Main(string[])'.  Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.`

Comment: I guess there are two main() method. Try to remove the one in my code, and rename it something else. Then call it from your main method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```
string originalText = textBox11.Text;
string[] splitString = originalText.Split(new Char [] {'N' , 'G', 'X', 'Y', 'I', 'J', 'H', 'K', 'F', 'T'});
```

And then access all of the numbers by using:

```
textBoxN.text = splitString[0];
textBoxG.text = splitString[1];
textBoxX.text = splitString[2];
textBoxY.text = splitString[3];
```

if I am not mistaken.

Comment: that was a perfect one. but if i didn't give a letter' A' in the text box means, its giving me an error called `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: I believe that is because you have fewer splits in your splitString array than you are trying to use. I suppose you could just use a Try Catch clause around the "textBoxN = splitString[0]" part. OR you could just loop through the splitString to never get out of bounds. :-)